# Java - Selection Sort - only switching once

Tags: java

So the first switch definitely occurs between the lowest value 3, and 5, but it doesn't keep going after that. This makes me think there is something wrong with one of the for loops?

> public class SelectionSort
>
> {
>
> public static void main (String[] args)
>
> {
>
> ```
>    int [] list;
>    list = new int[5];
>    list[0] = 4; 
>    list[1] = 5;
>    list[2] = 12;
>    list[3] = 9;
>    list[4] = 3;               
>    for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; ++i) {
>        int index = i;
>        for (int j = 1; j < list.length; ++j) {
>            if (list[j] < list[index]) {
>                int temp = list[j];
>                list[j] = list[index];
>                list[index] = temp;
>            }
>        }
>    }
>    for (int k = 0; k < list.length; ++k) {
>        System.out.print(list[k] + ", ");
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short versión:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)        
   for (int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++)
       if (list[j] < list[i]) {
           int temp = list[j];
           list[j] = list[i];
           list[i] = temp;
       }       
for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
   System.out.print(list[k] + ", ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after  `if (list[j] < list[index]) {`, you have to update index if boolean statement gets satisfied  so you need to  `index = j` and do the swap after

see follwing :

```
public class MySelectionSort {

    public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr){

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j] < arr[index]) 
                    index = j;

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];  
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Updating index was only part of the problem, realized after looking at your code had not set up j to be i + 1.

Comment: @JRHB where did I set up j to be i+1?

Comment: 6th line:    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    int index = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; ++j) {
        if (list[j] < list[index]) {
            index = j; }}
    if (index != i) {
        int temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[index];
        list[index] = i; }}
```

To cut down on the number of swaps, the loop on j should only be looking the best item to swap with item i. There should be at most one swap for each value of i. (That's what makes it a Selection sort. If you do multiple swaps for each i, you might as well be doing Bubble Sort.

But that's for efficiency. The reason your code isn't working is that you start the loop on j at j = 1 instead of j = i + 1.